# PrintDialog "Handle 0 not valid" and "Default Printer Not Set" weirdness

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

Sorry for the long post but I'm trying to get as much info out as possible for this strange situation.

I'm having an issue where if I show the PrintDialog, after I select a printer and click OK, I get an exception: **Handle 0 is not valid** .The stack trace is below.

```
   at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.SetHdevmode(IntPtr hdevmode)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog.UpdatePrinterSettings(IntPtr hDevMode, IntPtr hDevNames, Int16 copies, Int32 flags, PrinterSettings settings, PageSettings pageSettings)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog.ShowPrintDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner, WndProc hookProcPtr, PRINTDLG data)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at MyNamespace.PrintManager.PrintDialog(ReportDocument reportDocument)
   etc.
```

Here is the snippet of code leading up to the call...

```
PrintDialog pd = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
pd.AllowSelection = false;
pd.AllowPrintToFile = false;
pd.AllowSomePages = false;

// Exception occurs on next line after "OK" is clicked on the dialogue box.
if (pd.ShowDialog(null) == DialogResult.OK)   
{
 // etc.
```

If I examine the value of `pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName` before calling `pd.ShowDialog()`, the value is **Default printer is not set**, even though a default printer *is* actually set. Furthermore, I have tried writing to a log file `pd.PrintManager.DefaultPageSettings.ToString()` and I also get an exception, **No printers are installed** even though there are about six printers installed! (including "Send to One Note" and "Microsoft Xps writer", etc.)

Now here is where it gets weird: This issue only occurs on an installation of the application on a client's PC (Windows 10). Not on my own development PC (Windows 7) or a test computer running Windows 10 (same release & .Net Framework as client) I have here..

But stranger still: On the client's PC, other applications using the printer dialogue box run absolutely fine without a problem , as does a small tet application I created that just runs the snippet below and `MessageBox.Show()`s the chosen printer.

And even stranger: if I copy the same snippet of code to the beginning of the application (for the code above is only called when the user clicks on a "Print" button and a report is generated to be created) without showing the dialog box, then when it gets to this point, everything is fine once again!

But I'm not happy with this as a fix - our QA team have no way of validating it and I don't know why it's fixed now, or why it was a problem for this one client (and several others who have reported the problem) but not for most other people. Our process prevents me from just sticking it in and hoping for the best.

Has anyone come across this before? Is there something that could be causing .Net to "forget" there are printers installed (and a default printer assigned)?

The codebase is huge, I can't debug the problem on Visual Studio, and I can't access the client's PC regularly so I can't just isolate where it all goes wrong.

PDF995 is installed and the Report generating uses the [ReportPrinting Framework](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21505/A-ReportPrinting-Framework?msg=3765079) in case these are known to cause issues.

I've also seen [this post on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/31cad3b8-2c24-4915-8ee4-5e658b24a00e/windows-10-can-not-print-after-usign-managmentobject?forum=winforms) where it showed the same symptoms after `ManagementObjectSearcher` but while my application does use it, it doesn't go near it before this problem is encountered.

Comment: Neither QA nor the dev ever exercise a program long enough to get it into a state where handle allocations start to fail and error messages start to get wonky.  Only the end-user does.  Use a decent memory profiler to diagnose handle leaks.